# Javascript - getElementById() returns null even though the element exists

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the element with getElementById(), but it returns null.

This is the error I get on mozilla firefox debugger

> "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null".

What is wrong in the code?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stack</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .para1{position:absolute;top:10px;left:120px;z-index:0;border:solid;padding:80px;width:300px;background-color:aqua}
      .para2{position:absolute;top:50px;left:150px;z-index:0;border:solid;padding:80px;width:300px;background-color:#ff0}
      .para3{position:absolute;top:100px;left:180px;z-index:0;border:solid;padding:80px;width:300px;background-color:red}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="para1" id="p1" onmouseover="toTop('p1')">Frame One</p>
    <p class="para2" id="p2" onmouseover="toTop('p2')">Frame Three</p>
    <p class="para3" id="p3" onmouseover="toTop('p3')">Frame Two</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var top = 'p3';
      function toTop(newTop) {
        domTop = document.getElementById(top).style
        domNew = document.getElementById(newTop).style
        domTop.zIndex = "0"
        domNew.zIndex = "10"
        top = newTop
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does the first `getElementById()` take the parameter `top`?  That isn't set until the end of your function

Comment: @EatPeanutButter  `var top='p3'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`top` appears to be a reserved variable -- it resolves to `window.top` in your function. Try naming `top` something else like `_top` and you shouldn't get any errors.

Comment: Worked..Thank you so much

Comment: I believe `top` is a "host object"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script to something like something like:

```
(function(window, document, undefined){

// code that should be taken care of right away

  window.onload = init;

    function init(){
      var top='p3'
      function toTop(newTop) {
        domTop=document.getElementById(top).style
        domNew=document.getElementById(newTop).style
        domTop.zIndex="0"
        domNew.zIndex="10"
        top=newTop
      }
    }

})(window, document, undefined);
```

So that it isn't ran until after the document is fully loaded. I know the script is at the end of your body statement, but that could still be causing an issue.
Also it looks like your function is never actually called. You'll need to change it to an IIFE or add

```
toTop()
```

after the function